# Getting days of week from date field, with field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser, date

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.3 and have a field containing a date as following format M/D/Y. I need to get the day of the week based on my date field.

I need to do this from the field calculator.

Example of my data:

[image: Sample:]

```
def dayOfWeek(dField):
dow = datetime.strptime(dField , '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%A')
return dow

dayOfWeek(!evDate!)
```

but got error.

Comment: For coding questions, please include your best attempt code snippet within the question and let us know where you are stuck at.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python

Comment: Please refer to the question (edited version) which I included my code.

Comment: What does the error message say? Also, is your actual code indented, or is it written unindented as displayed above?

Comment: Even though this is using the Python Parser of the ArcGIS Field Calculator it seems likely to be a pure Python rather than GIS problem so I think you may be wise to research it using [so].

Comment: There isn't an ArcGIS 10.3.3, just 10.3 and 10.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VB Script will do that for you. Make sure your "Parser" is set to VB Script in the Field Calculator window.  The two function you need are:

- Weekday [returns numerical day of week 1-7]
- WeekdayName [converts prior function the word for the day of the week]

If you put the following into the Filed Calculator it will write the word day of the week.

```
=WeekdayName(weekday([evDate]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in field calculator (tested on a text field with date string like m/d/y format):

```
import datetime
def getDay(value):
  day_dict = {0:'Monday',1:'Tuesday',2:'Wednesday',3:'Thursday',4:'Friday',5:'Saturday',6:'Sunday'}
  if value:
    dayInt = datetime.datetime(int(value.split('/')[2]), int(value.split('/')[0]), int(value.split('/')[1])).weekday()
    return day_dict[dayInt]
```